# Implement a data access layer and connect to a database?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, c#-4.0

A week and 4 days of experience in C#, so please bear with me. 
I've been assigned the task of building a webform that will store information into a connected database. I have created a data access layer class where I want to connect the code that will display once someone has selected to edit/create a new entry.

I want the DAL to do 3 things:

1. `View` the table it will update
2. Add a record to the table i.e `insert`
3. `Update` a field in a previous entry

The following is the code I have so far:

```
public class AccountTrackerDAL
{ #region View ConnectionType()
  public DataTable ViewConnectionType()
   {  
      var sqlStatement = new StringBuilder();

      sqlStatement.Append(" SELECT");
      sqlStatement.Append(" ConnectionTypeID, ConnectionTypeDesc, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, LastUpdatedBy, LastUpdatedDate");
      sqlStatement.Append("  FROM");
      sqlStatement.Append("  dbo.ConnectionType");
      sqlStatement.Append("  ORDER BY");
      sqlStatement.Append("  ConnectionTypeDes");

       SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement.ToString());
       return DBAccess.SQLServer.GetDataTable(DBAccess.SQLServer.GetConnectionString("AccountTrackerDB",sqlCmd);
   }#endregion // This code has no errors and does what I want.

    #region View ConnectionType by Id

      public DataTable ViewConnectionTypeByID(int connectionTypeID)
      { var sqlStatement = new StringBuilder();

        sqlStatement.Append(" SELECT");
        sqlStatement.Append("   ConnectionTypeID, ConnectionTypeDesc, Created By, CreatedDate, LastUpdatedBy, LastUpdatedDate");
        sqlStatement.Append(" FROM");
        sqlStatement.Append( "   dbo.ConnectionType");
        sqlStatement.Append("  WHERE");
        sqlStatement.Append(" ConnectionTypeID = @ConnectionTypeID");

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement.ToString());
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConnectionTypeID", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@ConnectionTypeID"].Value = connectionTypeID;

        return DBAccess.SQLServer.GetDataTable(DBAccess.SQLServer.GetConnectionSTring("AccountTracker"),sqlCommand);
      }#endregion // this code also functions as i need it to, according to //my boss. Although I don't understand it.

#region Insert ConnectionType by Id /* I need this method to pass a value when the user chooses to not a hard coded value. In other words i just need to pass a place holder. Here is where i don't know what to pass */
       public DataTable UpdateConnectionTypeById(int connectionTypeID)
       { var sqlStatement = new StringBuilder();

         sqlStatement.Append("INSERT INTO");
         sqlStatement.Append("  ConnectionType"); 
         sqlStatement.Append(" WHERE");
         sqlStatement.Append(" ConnecitonTypeID = @ConnectionID"); 

         SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement.ToString());
         sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConnectionTypeid"), SqlDbType.Int);
         sqlCommand.Parameters[@ConnectionTypeid].Value = connectionTypeID;

         return DBAccess.SQLServer.GetDataTable(DBAccess.SQLServer.GetConnectionString("AccounTracker"),sqlCommand);
       }#endregion

}
```

I'll do my best to answer questions anyone may have. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any specific questions about the code you posted?

Comment: how should i write the code thats related to the 3rd region view to correctly update a the fields entered by the user? Perhaps better worded, how do I add a place holder that will update when the user requests to edit an entry?

Comment: your question is still not clear. what are you really trying to do?

Comment: strictly speaking, the DAL must have no knowledge of the user interface layer and vise-versa

Comment: For this specific kind of string concatenation, there is no advantage to using a stringbuilder over regular concatenation.

Comment: I strongly suggest, for numerous reasons including prevention of *SQL injection* attacks; better access control; increased cohesion; reduced coupling; and improved code readability; that you implement your CRUD operations in QL Stored Procedures. That will also simplify your C# code considerably, and ease writing the SQL because you won't have all these string concatenations cluttering the client code base.

Comment: @Aniket, Won't the DAL have the ability to alter the tables it's connected to, through the database? The first method let's me view the table,  the second method has the same functionality but it is ordered by the connectionTypeId. For the 3rd function, I'd like to create place holders that will allow me to Insert data into those tables. (Is that performing an action that should be handled elsewhere?)